# Tensorflow: Word2vec CBOW model

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

I am new to tensorflow and to word2vec. I just studied the [word2vec_basic.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.8/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) which trains the model using `Skip-Gram` algorithm. Now I want to train using `CBOW` algorithm. Is it true that this can be achieved if I simply reverse the `train_inputs` and `train_labels`?

Comment: [link](http://www.cnblogs.com/edwardbi/p/5509699.html) FYI, but it's written in Chinese.

Comment: @idailylife haha thanks, I am Chinese

Answer (score 14):

I think `CBOW` model can not simply be achieved by flipping the `train_inputs` and the `train_labels` in `Skip-gram` because `CBOW` model architecture uses the sum of the vectors of surrounding words as one single instance for the classifier to predict. E.g., you should use `[the, brown]` together to predict `quick` rather than using `the` to predict `quick`.

[image]

To implement CBOW, you'll have to write a new `generate_batch` generator function and sum up the vectors of surrounding words before applying logistic regression. I wrote an example you can refer to: https://github.com/wangz10/tensorflow-playground/blob/master/word2vec.py#L105

Comment: @Zichen Wang Why would you sum in word2vec._init_graph() (lines 216-217) instead of in generate_batch_cbow() (line 132)? You would be passing a much smaller matrix and you would avoid using a for loop/extra lookups within tf.

Comment: @Zichen Wang I think it is slightly better to do lookup and sum in generate_batch then pass the sum of embeddings rather than all indices, but I haven't tried it

Answer (score 10):

For CBOW, You need to change only few parts of the code [word2vec_basic.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.8/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py). Overall the training structure and method are the same.

Which parts should I change in word2vec_basic.py?

1) The way it generates training data pairs. Because in CBOW, you are predicting the center word, not the context words.

The new version for `generate_batch` will be

```
def generate_batch(batch_size, bag_window):
  global data_index
  span = 2 * bag_window + 1 # [ bag_window target bag_window ]
  batch = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, span - 1), dtype=np.int32)
  labels = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, 1), dtype=np.int32)  
  buffer = collections.deque(maxlen=span)
  for _ in range(span):
    buffer.append(data[data_index])
    data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(data)
  for i in range(batch_size):
    # just for testing
    buffer_list = list(buffer)
    labels[i, 0] = buffer_list.pop(bag_window)
    batch[i] = buffer_list
    # iterate to the next buffer
    buffer.append(data[data_index])
    data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(data)
  return batch, labels
```

Then new training data for CBOW would be

```
data: ['anarchism', 'originated', 'as', 'a', 'term', 'of', 'abuse', 'first', 'used', 'against', 'early', 'working', 'class', 'radicals', 'including', 'the']

#with bag_window = 1:
    batch: [['anarchism', 'as'], ['originated', 'a'], ['as', 'term'], ['a', 'of']]
    labels: ['originated', 'as', 'a', 'term']
```

compared to Skip-gram's data

```
#with num_skips = 2 and skip_window = 1:
    batch: ['originated', 'originated', 'as', 'as', 'a', 'a', 'term', 'term', 'of', 'of', 'abuse', 'abuse', 'first', 'first', 'used', 'used']
    labels: ['as', 'anarchism', 'originated', 'a', 'term', 'as', 'a', 'of', 'term', 'abuse', 'of', 'first', 'used', 'abuse', 'against', 'first']
```

2) Therefore you also need to change the variable shape

```
train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
```

to

```
train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, bag_window * 2])
```

3) loss function

```
 loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
  weights = softmax_weights, biases = softmax_biases, inputs = tf.reduce_sum(embed, 1), labels = train_labels, num_sampled= num_sampled, num_classes= vocabulary_size))
```

Notice **inputs = tf.reduce_sum(embed, 1)** as Zichen Wang mentioned it.

This is it!

Comment: "Notice inputs = tf.reduce_sum(embed, 1) as Zichen Wang mentioned it." That would take the average across the whole batch, you need to take the average across the context window.

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 No. Axis 1 is a window size, not a batch size.

Comment: It's been a while, so I can't comment on this with confidence, but I remember my testing had found that the average was being taken across the batch, so I had to change it.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, yes:

for the given text `the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog:`, the CBOW instances for window size 1 would be

```
([the, brown], quick), ([quick, fox], brown), ([brown, jumped], fox), ...
```

Comment: And then the input-output pair should be: (the, quick), (brown, quick), (quick, brown),(fox, brown),..... right?