# Tensorflow: tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, nlp, pydev

I'm working on a project to fulfill text categorization. When dealing with the word-to-vector, i'm recommended to use `tensorflow.contrib.layers.embed_sequence`. But, it seems that this API does not offer a  illustration of encoding method. So, i wonder how this API acutally works.

By the way, i am using pydev to pydev development and i hava successfully installed `tensorflow` module. Program using `tensorflow` runs properly. But when i want to open declaration of tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence, it says:

```
"NameError: name tf is not defined"...
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: @gionni, What encoding methond does tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence adopt？

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can use `tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence` in this way,

```
word_embed = tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence(
                        features,
                        vocab_size=VOCAB_SIZE, 
                        embed_dim=EMBEDDING_SIZE)
```

For the tutorial of `embed_sequence`, please checkout the [official doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/d86d570faaa63cf7815a55379d91919ffde2699d#diff-b3a2a62db345de7e16a8873c920d0d50R91) or [other answers on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44280918/456105)

For the tutorial of text categorization, please checkout this blog
https://medium.com/@ilblackdragon/tensorflow-text-classification-615198df9231

Comment: Thanks, But is there more informotion about this API except for its basic syntax? I want to know is this API based on One-hot encoding or Word2Vec or other encoding method?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question - are you asking what algorithm (e.g. skip-gram vs continuous bag-of-words) is used by Tensorflow to produce word embeddings?

If so - [Tensorflow: Word2vec CBOW model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394970/tensorflow-word2vec-cbow-model) suggests that Skip-Gram is the default, and this https://github.com/wangz10/tensorflow-playground/blob/master/word2vec.py#L105 suggests how to switch it to CBOW.