# How to calculate which word approximately fits best given a context and possible words?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Unfortunately, I don't find anything which helps me with my problem.

I have a sentence like

```
 if the age of the applicant is higher than 18, then ...
```

and a list of words like

```
 higher, bigger, greater, wider
```

which are all quite synonymous, because say, that something is
 greater.

Now I want to find out, which of the given words approximately fits
 the best at the predefined position in the sentence.

The best fitting word in this example would be 'greater', but for
 example 'higher' would be also fine. In my specific case, I want to
 show an error message if someone would write 'wider' because this
 doesn't make sense in this semantic context.

So I want to have a look at the keyword, which is always unambiguously
 in this example, and the given possible words like the four words I
 mentioned above.  Now I want to calculate which one of the possible
 words would fit approximately the best in place of the keyword in this
 semantic context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple, single, answer to this. But as a starting point you could check out Continuous Bag-of-Words (CBOW) word embeddings, which aim at predicting a word given its context.

As an example on how to implement it, you could refer to: [Tensorflow: Word2vec CBOW model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394970/tensorflow-word2vec-cbow-model) and the original Word2Vec Code Archive: https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/